# UIView animate - Rotate and scale up, then rotate and scale down

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, rotation, uiviewanimation

I have a subclassed imageview that I'd like to fade in, scale up, and rotate, then continue rotating while scaling back down and fading out.

I am using a UIView animate block with a completion handler to handle the shrinking back down.

The problem is it's not a fluid animation. Before the completion handler runs, the animation stops before running again. I need it to be one nice "swoop" of an animation.

**Code below:**

```
    let duration: TimeInterval = 3.0
    let rotate = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi))


    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration * 3, delay: 0, options: [.curveLinear], animations: {
        // initial transform
        self.alpha = 0
        self.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.1, y: 0.1)
        // initial spin for duration of animaton
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration * 3, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveLinear], animations: {
            self.transform = rotate
        }, completion: nil)

        // scaling and fading
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0, options: [.curveLinear], animations: {
            UIView.setAnimationRepeatCount(3)
            self.transform = self.transform.scaledBy(x: 0.8, y: 0.8)
            self.alpha = 1
        }) { (true) in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, animations: {
                UIView.setAnimationRepeatCount(3)
                self.transform = self.transform.scaledBy(x: 0.1, y: 0.1)
                self.alpha = 0
            })
        }
    }, completion: nil)
```

How can I get the animation to rotate *the entire time* while fading in and scaling up before scaling back down and fading out? The entire animation should last 3 seconds, and repeat 3 times. Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at keyframe animations?

Comment: I agree with Donnovan King... you should probably drop from the `UIView` animation level down to a keyframe animation accomplished through Core Animation directly.  That will make your entire animation one continuous loop.

Comment: Donovan and Scott - by keyframe animation, do you mean animating with cabasicanimation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your modified request I am expanding what you already saw using the block animations.  As some have said, key frame animations may be better, regardless, here is the thought.

Create an animation that rotates the entire time by transforming the view.
Create another animation that does the scaling and fading based off the current transform (which is rotating).  In this pass, I just created some variable to allow you to customize (and repeat) portions of the animation.  I broke some things out to be clear and know I could refactor to write thing even more concise.

Here is the code

```
import UIKit

class OrangeView: UIView {



override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

  let duration: TimeInterval = 9.0

  self.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity

  // initial transform
  self.alpha = 1
  self.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.1, y: 0.1)

  // start rotation
  rotate(duration: duration)

  // scaling and fading
  scaleUpAndDown(desiredRepetitions: 3, initalDuration: duration)


  }

func rotate(duration: TimeInterval) {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: duration/2.0,
                               delay: 0.0,
                               options: [.curveLinear], animations: {
                                let angle = Double.pi
                                self.transform = self.transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(angle))
                }, completion: {[weak self] finished in
  guard let strongSelf = self else {
    return
  }
  if finished &&
    strongSelf.transform != CGAffineTransform.identity {
    strongSelf.rotate(duration: duration)
  } else {
    // rotation ending
  }
})

  }

func scaleUpAndDown(timesRepeated: Int = 0, desiredRepetitions: Int, initalDuration: TimeInterval) {

guard timesRepeated < desiredRepetitions,
  desiredRepetitions > 0, initalDuration > 0 else {
  self.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
    return
}
let repeatedCount = timesRepeated + 1

let scalingDuration = initalDuration/2.0/Double(desiredRepetitions)

UIView.animate(withDuration: scalingDuration,
               delay: 0.0,
               animations: {
                let desiredOriginalScale: CGFloat = 0.8

                let scaleX = abs(CGAffineTransform.identity.a / self.transform.a) * desiredOriginalScale
                let scaleY = abs(CGAffineTransform.identity.d / self.transform.d) * desiredOriginalScale

                self.transform = self.transform.scaledBy(x: scaleX, y: scaleY)
                self.alpha = 1
              }) { (true) in
                UIView.animate(withDuration:scalingDuration,
                               delay: 0.0,
                               animations: {

                                let desiredOriginalScale: CGFloat = 0.1

                                let scaleX = abs(CGAffineTransform.identity.a / self.transform.a) * desiredOriginalScale
                                let scaleY = abs(CGAffineTransform.identity.d / self.transform.d) * desiredOriginalScale
                                  self.transform = self.transform.scaledBy(x: scaleX, y: scaleY)
                                  self.alpha = 0
                }) { finshed in
                  self.scaleUpAndDown(timesRepeated: repeatedCount, desiredRepetitions: desiredRepetitions, initalDuration: initalDuration);
                }
              }

  }

}
```

Finally here is another animated gif

[image]

Comment: Happy to help!  What is interesting its the `...transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(angle))`.  Say if your angle is 2π, 360 deg, the transform will take the shortest path to complete and since it was already at the ending transform nothing will happen.  Thus to get a full rotation, we rotate by π (180 deg) and then upon completion, rotate by 180 deg again in the completion block.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

I see the slight stutter in rotation at the start of the onCompletion.

I created a reduction with your code (shown below in the Blue View) and a variation in the Orange View.  This was taken from the simulator and turned into an animated GIF, so speed is slowed down.  The Orange View continues to spin as the complete transform just scales down.

This is the code for the layoutSubviews() for the Orange View

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    
    let duration: TimeInterval = 3.0
    let rotate = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi))
    
    // initial transform
    self.alpha = 0
    self.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.1, y: 0.1)
    
    // initial spin for duration of animaton
    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration,
                   delay: 0.0,
                   options: [.curveLinear],
                   animations: {
                      self.transform = rotate;
                    },
                   completion: nil)
    // scaling and fading
    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration/2.0, animations: {
      self.transform = self.transform.scaledBy(x: 0.8, y: 0.8)
      self.alpha = 1
    }) { (true) in
      UIView.animate(withDuration: duration/2.0, animations: {
        self.transform = self.transform.scaledBy(x: 0.1, y: 0.1)
        self.alpha = 0
      })
    }
  }
```

Comment: this is awesome! And thank you for taking the time to create a gif of the end result! Is there a way to add a repeat count to your orange animation? I tried adding setAnimationRepeatCount (3) to the scaling and fading block, but it chops up the animation into 3 "bits"

Comment: I've marked your answer as correct, since it does what I asked. repeating the animation 3x wasn't in the scope of my original question, but if you can help get the orange view animation to repeat 3x, it'd be appreciated :) i'm getting very odd results adding setAnimationRepeatCount in your block.

Comment: Are you looking to repeat the entire animation 3 times over the 3 second duration?  Or are you wanting the to say extend the duration of the entire animation to 9 seconds for the animation to repeat (rotation and scale/fade)?

Comment: The latter! :) I'm looking for the entire animation to last for 9 seconds. During the 9 seconds, the "orange view" will do its rotate + alpha + scale 3 times. I wrapped your entire animation in another animation block for 9 seconds, then set the inner animations to 3 seconds, but I'm not getting expected results. My original post is edited

Comment: I added a possible solution as another answer below since I could not put an image in the comments.  Hope this helps and I am sure you could improve it further.  Have a good weekend!

Answer (score 1):

Try using CGAffineTransformConcat()

```
  CGAffineTransform scale = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.8, 0.8);
  self.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(CGAffineTransformRotate(self.transform, M_PI / 2), scale);
```

Comment: By calling a function like scaledBy on an existing transform it is already performing the concatenation.